# device dev/sda not found or ignored by filtering using vmware (openstack)

Tags: openstack, lvm, fdisk

i'm trying to install a storage node to use with openstack, this procedure requires installing LVM on this particular node, so i try to follow the official guide but i get this problem (check the title) whenever i try to execute "pvcreate /dev/sda".

error : device dev/sda not found or ignored by filtering

i checked the file lvm.config under /etc/lvm and i have nothing filtered.

searched for all possible solutions online and tried most of them but nothing worked.

any help would be appreciated, 
thank you,

Comment: If my training serves me right you should be adding a partition like `dev/sda1` and not just `/dev/sda` create a partition of type lvm then add it..

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** Probably `/dev/sda` is not empty. Make sure you're okay with destroying data on it.

You have to erase the partiotion table of the device. Here is a quote from `pvcreate` manpage:

> For  DOS disk partitions, the partition id should be set to 0x8e using
>   fdisk(8), cfdisk(8), or a equivalent. For GUID Partition Table (GPT),
>   the id is E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928. **For whole disk devices
>   only the partition table must be erased, which will effectively
>   destroy all data on that disk.** This can be done by zeroing the first
>   sector with:
>
> ```
>    dd if=/dev/zero of=PhysicalVolume bs=512 count=1
> ```

BTW, in my case the error message was a little different: `Device /dev/sda excluded by a filter.` Probably I have a newer LVM version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have nothing filtered, check the type of partition you have set.

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

If the partition type is not Linux LVM, you'll need to change it.

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

change the type ( t ) to 8e, then write the changes. You should be all set after that.

Comment: `dev/sda` is not a partition but a device!

Answer (score 0):

**For openstack installation :**

if you created two virtual machine node (compute node and controller node)
using virtual box.

on compute node you tried : pvcreate /dev/sdb

error : device dev/sdb not found or ignored by filtering

**solution :**

1.power off compute node (compute virtual machine)
2.go to virtual box & click on settings for compute node
3.go to storage & in controller:SATA click on add hard disk
4.create hard disk (10GB)(eg: disk1.vdi)
5.start compute node
6.now in compute node, goto /etc/dev folder and type sdb (you will see sdb)
(do not use terminal,go in directory wise for simplicity)
7.now go to terminal, logged in as super user(sudo su)
8.now try : pvcreate /dev/sdb